# How to install "stunnel" on CloudLinux RHEL Feddora CentOS yum install not working

Tags: centos, cpanel, stunnel

**!!JUST WRITING THIS POST SO THAT SOMEONE CAN SAVE HOURS IN THIS!!**

I tried a hell lot to install this **"stunnel"** but was unable to do so
I was in my cpanel's terminal

What I tried all with 'sudo'

```
yum install stunnel
yum -y install stunnel
yum install stunnel5u
yum install stunnel4
```

etc BUT NONE OF THEM WORKED it just said `No package stunnel found`

I thought of manually install but still failed
I followed
https://developers.exlibrisgroup.com/blog/newcastle-stunnel-manual-installing-stunnel-on-centos-6/

[image]
I tried with the latest version though 5.57

But I stuck on makefile as for this entire stunnel tar package I don't know how to create a makefile

[image]

Please Help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched everywhere but I didn't find it so I tried it myself and it worked
Hope this may help others who are stuck with this in their  `cpanel RHEL FEDDORA CENTOS`

What I did is this:
`Open Terminal from Cpanel and run this`

```
wget https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/7/x86_64/stunnel5u-5.44-1.ius.centos7.x86_64.rpm

rpm -Uvh stunnel5u-5.44-1.ius.centos7.x86_64*rpm
```

This gave me sign of relief

[image]